# How can I check if a function throws an error which contains a text in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

```
function foo() {
  throw new Error('an error from (foo)');
}
```

I want to check if the error contains the text `(foo)`, I tried:

```
expect(() => foo()).toThrow(expect.stringContaining('(foo)'))
```

But which is failed and does not work as expected:

```
 ● test › checks error containing text

    expect(received).toThrowError(expected)

    Expected asymmetric matcher: StringContaining "(foo)"

    Received name:    "Error"
    Received message: "an error from (foo)"

          1 | function foo() {
        > 2 |   throw new Error('an error from (foo)');
            |         ^
```

Although I can find a way with regex like:

```
expect(() => foo()).toThrowError(/[(]foo[)]/)
```

But which requires me to escape some special characters, which is not what I want.

Why is `expect.stringContaining` not supported in this case? Or do I miss anything?

A small demo for trying: https://github.com/freewind-demos/typescript-jest-expect-throw-error-containing-text-demo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`toThrow` doesn't accept a matcher. Per [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror) the optional error argument has four options:

> You can provide an optional argument to test that a specific error is
> thrown:
>
> - regular expression: error message **matches** the pattern
> - string: error message **includes** the substring
> - error object: error message is **equal to** the message property of the object
> - error class: error object is **instance of** class

In your case you can use either:

- the regex option

  ```
   .toThrow(/\(foo\)/)
  ```

  (you don't need a character class just to escape parentheses) or by running the string through a function to escape it for you (see e.g. [Is there a RegExp.escape function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/3001761)) then passing it to `new RegExp`; or
- the string option

  ```
   .toThrow("(foo)")
  ```